# File is being saved with Content-Disposition header

Tags: java, angular, multipartform-data, dropwizard

I have angular2 front-end and Dropwizard back-end. I'm trying to upload a picture from front-end to back-end.

My html code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" (change)="fileChange($event)">
```

My component:

```
fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        let file: File = fileList[0];
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        this.siteDescriptionService.sendPhoto(formData).subscribe(value => {
            console.log("value", value);
        });
    }
}
```

My service:

```
sendPhoto(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.postPhoto('api/site/savePhoto', data, null).map(res => res);
}
```

My http interceptor:

```
postPhoto(url: string, params?: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    this.beforeRequest();
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    let reqOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return super.post(this.getFullUrl(url), params, reqOptions)
        .catch(this.onCatch)
        .do((res: Response) => {
            this.onSuccess(res);
        }, (error: any) => {
            this.onError(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            this.onFinally();
        });
}
```

The request is being send with such payload:

------WebKitFormBoundaryAz4AnN4lFPWKUvmH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="logo.png"
Content-Type: image/png

------WebKitFormBoundaryAz4AnN4lFPWKUvmH--

And on my server I have:

```
@POST
@Timed
@Path("savePhoto")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response uploadFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream) throws IOException {
    String uploadedFileLocation = "/tmp/photo1.png";


    FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart().field("file", uploadedInputStream, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE);

    FormDataBodyPart p = part.getField("file");
    InputStream i = (InputStream) p.getEntity();

    writeToFile( i, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;
    return Response.ok(output).build();
}

private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation)
        throws IOException {
    int read;
    final int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

Everything is fine, file is being saved, but it's saved with the whole request payload, including `Content-Disposition`, `Content-Type` headers, etc., and therefore the file becomes "broken".

How can I remove the Content-Disposition header from file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an `InputStream` parameter, you're saying you want to whole request body. If you just want a single part, you need to annotate it with `@FormDataParam` with the name of the part

```
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
                           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fdcd) {
    String filename = fcdc.getFileName();

    // You don't need to create the FormDataMultiPart
    // just save the InputStream parameter
}
```

In order for this to work, you also need to to register the `MutliPartFeature`

```
env.jersey().register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Comment: I've tried that, but Jersey (if I get it right) returns 400 error.

Comment: That means it's a client side error. You shouldn't be setting the Content-Type header to multipart/form-date on the client when using JS client. By doing this, you don't have the boundary, which would cause Jersey to reject it. You're supposed to let the Browser create the header value. I think you do that by setting the Content-Tpye header value to undefined. If that doesn't work, do a search for how to send files with Angular. Answers should mention something about this problem and provide the right approach

Comment: I've tried without Content-Type: multipart/form-data, but it didn't work also. I googled a lot, but haven't find any solution. I've had to create additional servlet for this, and it works perfectly (yes, I send picture from client without multipart/form-data header). But I'm still very interested in this approach.

Comment: When I remove the header, the boundary appears. Browser adds this: Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary1uqVbHzzENKo4azE

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work with Jersey if it works using the Servlet API. And you sure the result is still 400? What is the exact error message. There should be one returned. Or even an error being logged on the server.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't return much. In browser I have only this: {"code":400,"message":"HTTP 400 Bad Request"}.  And in the server logs theres this: 127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2017:07:04:57 +0000] "POST /api/site/uploadImage HTTP/1.1" 400 45 "http://localhost:8181/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36" 139

Comment: Try to add a generic `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` and log the stack trace. I think there should be an error but for some reason Dropwizard is swallowing it up. If you get a 400, there is almost always an exception thrown somewhere. It's just a matter of how it is handled. Try extending [this   mapper](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/errors/LoggingExceptionMapper.java) and registering it

Comment: Thanks to your advice I've catched the exception an the details were:

detailMessage: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'imagejpeg'
cause: java.text.ParseException: End of header.

Turns out my data filter was removing the '/' sign from the media type.

Thank you very much for your help, sir!